# search more than one consecutive chars and replace with single char, also exclude certain chars

Tags: regex, perl

search more than one consecutive chars and replace with single char, also exclude certain chars.
Ex:
`Saaleem` I need `Saleem`

`0 ++ ((1*0.04526)*1.05* 1)` I need `0 + ((1*0.04526)*1.05* 1)`

The below replace everything, i need to exclude few chars as well - in this case `(` & `e`.

```
$str =~ s/(.)\1+/$1/g;
```

Comment: Do you really want to change things like `11 * 11` to `1 * 1`? If those are mathematical formulas, that could be problematic.

Comment: Good point, will have to add the numbers [0-9] also. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude what you need to by using a [negating character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
([^(e])\1+
```

Here's a regex101 to play with: https://regex101.com/r/rX0oH8/2

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.` with something more accurate,

```
$str =~ s/([^e(])\1+/$1/g;
```